# How could there be avodah zara in the era of revealed miracles?

Tags: avodah-zarah, miracle

Before the Babylonian exile, there was an era of publicly revealed open miracles such as the ones that occurred daily in the Temple, as well as widespread prophecy.

How then can we explain the existence avodah zara described in the Nach (e.g. of the likes that had to be eradicated in a great effort by King Yoshiyahu)?

Imagine if today we had a Temple where there would be constant daily occurrences defying the laws of physics, and also if we had a multitude of Jewish observant individuals who would correctly predict future events via prophecy, leaving absolutely no room for doubt that it was due to any kind of chance. Would there be anyone who would remain an atheist or agnostic, or anyone who would worship anything else but Judaism? It would immediately be all over the news and twitter, spread through social media and word of mouth, and everyone would likely be forming lines to convert to Judaism.

And we're considered on a lower level, due to yeridas hadoros and being farther from Matan Torah, to the generations of the First Temple. Yet they had all these open miracles and prophets, and yet avodah zara still existed. How can that be explained?

Granted, the yetzer hara for idolatry has been removed in the Second Temple era and beyond, so we can't really imagine the intensity of that desire. Is that, however, enough to explain counteracting actually witnessing nature-defying miracles?

Comment: There are unfortunately many people who know it is immoral and fleeting to engage in promiscuity, zera levatala or even adultery, but their primal desires get the better of them.

Comment: I think you're vastly overestimating the power of what we believe, and vastly underestimating the power of what we want. Ask any public figure why they threw their lives, family, and career away for a fleeting desire. Ask anyone who tries to diet.

Comment: Closing a question just because a somewhat similar one (from years ago) exists - with no answers - accomplishes nothing constructive to provide an actual answer. Sometimes questions have to be re-asked and resurfaced.

Comment: @user9806 The constructive things marking duplicates accomplishes are reducing redundant work, consolidating content, and increasing search efficiency. See too the [help] pages https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: the first help page actually says “In general, the original question must have an answer”, which just underscores my point - closing a question which restates an old  (forgotten about) question that had no answers, further inhibits answers to that question.

Comment: @user9806 It definitely does not further inhibit answers. The other question is still open. All this does is direct people to answer there. What you call forgotten I'd call "needs advertising". If you care about it, post links to it elsewhere to draw attention to it. Posting it again accidentally is essentially that, but please don't abuse the platform by posting duplicates intentionally.

Comment: In any event if you have questions or suggestions for better site policies, please ask on [meta]

Comment: Why not close that one instead? This one already has discussion on it.

Answer (score 0):

The Avodah Zorahs also had (false) apparent power. The Ramban says that because there is no Beis Hamkdash where open miracles are taking places the idolaters priests have lost their power to perform miracles as well to even things out and keep Emunah a nisyon.

Furthermore when people have a Yetzer Hora there are no limits to what they can end up (not) believing. It's a  wonder how people worshipped carved wooden or stone items that were clearly human made. Even so, doing so  makes a lot more sense than the common current  Western belief that gender is a social construct. Men are woman as well as the converse if they identify as such. I can't think of  a single group in the history of the world that believed something so contrary to what their own eyes were seeing.  But as above people can believe anything no matter how absurd when the Yetzer Horah tells them to

Comment: Interesting answer re what the Ramban said, thank you.